# Can Mockito detect mock usage and field assignments?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

This use case is perhaps best explained by the test:

```
@Test
public void testZeroInteraction() {
    Pika pika = new Pika();
    Trainer trainer=mock(Trainer.class);

    pika.doNothing3(trainer);
    verifyZeroInteractions(trainer);
}
```

This is my `doNothing3()` method in class `Pika`:

```
void doNothing3(Trainer trainerIn){
    trainer=trainerIn;
    trainerIn.name="Ash";
}
```

In this case, `verifyZeroInteractions()` does not complain and the test passes.

Can Mockito detect assignments as those in the `doNothing3` method above?

If so, what Mockito method can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OO is about **behavior**, not *state*.

Right the first paragraph in the Mockito [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html) reads:

> Let's verify some behaviour! ...

In that sense; when Mockito talks about *interaction*, what they (or any other mocking framework to my knowledge) mean is: method calls.

In other words: the **mocked** object knows *nothing* about the fields of the class it is mocking.

So, you could basically do the following:

1. keep your current `testZeroInteraction()` test (to prove that **no methods** are called)
2. add a second test, to check that a real input object doesn't change

Like:

```
@Test
public void testFieldUpdates() {
  Pika pika = new Pika();
  Trainer orig = new Trainer();  
  Trainer copy = new Trainer(orig);
  pika.doNothing3(copy);
  assertThat(orig, is(copy));
```

}

What this test "means": create a trainer object, and then create a copy of that. Pass the first object into your method; and afterwards check if that object still `equals` the copy.

But of course - that requires that you have some sort of "copy constructor"; and also a reasonable implementation of `equals()`.

Finally: you should actually start by stepping back. My first sentence is: "OO is about behavior, not state". Translating to: the idea of having a Trainer class with **public writeable** fields is a **design smell**. You shouldn't do that. You don't create objects, pass them around and have other code directly write to fields. You call **methods** on other objects, you don't manipulate their state.

In other words: your approach violates a whole set of important OO principles. And because of that, Mockito is not supporting what you are doing. Because *nobody* should be doing what you are doing. So, as said: the *real* answer here is to fix your broken design.

Comment: GhostCat, thank you for this detailed answer. I agree - the public accessibility of fields is an issue and should instead be taken care of using getters and setters. But - I guess this relates to Mockito internals - Mockito could have just as easily implemented support for the fields, right? After all, fields and functions are both tied to the object as members.

Comment: Honestly: I can't say. You see, when you write a mock object, then you still have **method** calls coming in. You have some **active** trigger. Whereas a field update is like "passive". In essence, it is just a write to some memory location. There is "nothing" in that path that would trigger something on the object you wrote to. I would be really surprised if this is possible; even in a dirty hack-ish way of things.

Comment: Interesting. So, by the same token, it would be hard to know whether the line `trainer=trainerIn;` is executed, as it's just reading the memory address of `trainerIn`.

Comment: The only way to check that: *trainer* is obviously a field on some other class. You would have to check the *state* of that *other* class then.

Comment: GhostCat I'm trying to understand your statement "OO is about behavior, not state." Granted, it's going out-of-scope of the question a little. As I understand, an object encompasses both state (fields) and behavior (methods) 
[http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mitra/csSpring2017/cs303/lectures/oop.html ]. So when you say OOP is about behavior, are you referring to something along the lines of data encapsulation, or data hiding?

Comment: The focus is on state. Of course you need *internal* state to implement behavior. But: the external interface of a class should ideally provide behavior - not state. You might want to read about the "tell don't ask" principle for example.

Comment: *Mocking* is about behavior and not state, but OO is about state *and* behavior. The very definition of an object says it encapsulates state and behavior (rant mode: although these days OO went out of fashion, and most Java code is written in procedural style with non-objects such as anemic entities/value "objects" and stateless "services", "repositories", etc. which are essentially just a bunch of static-like methods).

Comment: @Rogério **Encapsulates**. That is the point. Yes, there is state. But is internal. It is secret. It is an implementation detail that nobody outside the encapsulation should know about. Methods are there to be called (the public ones at least). Fields are there ... so that the *internal* methods can make use of them. As soon as you expose fields to the outside world, you ask for trouble. Because now, all of a sudden you have code that *might* depend on accessing these fields. And worse: in the given example the OP wants to have those fields **writable**.

Comment: @Rogério Actually *exposing* fields is what makes people write procedural code. Because now, you find in class B: `if (foo.bar => 42) { doSomething()`. Alex Sharp wrote in **1977**: `We need to rethink our objects so that we can simply ask the objects to process themselves. 
Procedural code gets information then makes decisions. Object-oriented code tells objects to do things.` (from Smalltalk by Example). In that sense: if you think that having public readable, heck writable fields helps with doing OOP; well; I tend to disagree.

Comment: I said nothing about exposing internal fields as public. My point is that saying that OO is not about state doesn't make much sense - of course the state is usually encapsulated.